# Compare Datetime

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I have some exception files which I want to be deleted after 14 days or so. But how can I compare the date times?

It actually looks like this, but it does not work.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newDate = date.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(date.Day + 14));
DirectoryInfo exceptionsDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(pathToSave);

foreach (FileInfo actualFile in exceptionsDirectory.GetFiles())
{
    if (actualFile.LastWriteTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(date.Day + 14)) == newDay)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(actualFile.FullName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do ..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
DateTime expirydate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

DirectoryInfo exceptionsDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(pathToSave);

foreach (FileInfo actualFile in exceptionsDirectory.GetFiles())
{
    if (actualFile.LastWriteTime < expirydate)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(actualFile.FullName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do ..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As with most `DateTime` related answers this would be better if it used `DateTime.UtcNow` and `actualFile.LastWriteTimeUtc`. It doesn't matter in this case since the question said "14 days or so" but in case anyone takes this code and tries to apply it to, say, one hour old files, they ought to use Utc.

Comment: @IanMercer, it's not always good idea. In many situations you MUST rely on local and not on UTC time.

Comment: I didn't say "always", I said "most". For instance: nearly every multi-user application running on a server (WWW, WCF, WebApi, ...) has no use for `DateTime.Now`. Whenever you need to calculate the difference between two times you need to use Utc. etc. etc.  And even when you do need to work with local time you are better off using `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime` because it captures both Utc and the current offset.